# Turning off DMA on Linux still supported

Tags: linux, hdparm

Trying to turn off DMA on my Linux machine returns:

```
HDIO_GET_DMA failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I remember that this used to work to turn DMA on or off. I also tried using the kernel parameter `libata.dma=0` but it had no effect! The ATA driver and DMA seem to work well however. So I just wonder weather I should worry about this or it is just not supported anymore.

The distro is Ubuntu 12 and the kernel is 3.5.0-54-generic. The chipset is

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HDIO_*_DMA` are not supported by libata.

See https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Libata_FAQ:

> Older, unsupported ioctls
>
> Why does HDIO_SET_DMA fail? I want to use DMA! Why does
>   HDIO_SET_UNMASKINTR fail?
>
> libata intentionally does not support all the HDIO_xxx ioctls that
>   were supported by the older IDE driver. It is now preferred to use
>   SG_IO as a generalized ATA command submission method, rather than
>   creating a myriad of ioctls for each specific purpose.
>
> The design decision was made only to support the HDIO_xxx ioctls that
>   were heavily used by other programs. Generally the driver always
>   programs the hardware to its maximum capability automatically,
>   completely without user intervention. Therefore, for example,
>   HDIO_SET_DMA is not needed for the vast majority of users because DMA
>   is automatically enabled and used where available.